# Match String json array response for each element in Karate

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, karate

I have an api which returns string json array in response as follows. There are other elements as well in response.

```
"contacts": [
  "externaldeveloper1@exampledomain.com",
  "externa2developer1@exampledomain.com"
]
```

Now I need to match each element in this array to check its value.

In feature file:

```
When method POST
Then status 200
* match  response.contacts contains ['externaldeveloper1@exampledomain.com', externa2developer1@exampledomain.com]
```

But am getting syntax error:

```
match  response.contacts contains ['externaldeveloper1@exampledomain.com', externa2developer1@exampledomain.com]
```

Even I am doing 
`assert response.contacts.[0] == 'externaldeveloper1@exampledomain.com'` this also fails. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. You must have some typo or basic mistake somewhere.

```
* def response = { "contacts": [ "externaldeveloper1@exampledomain.com", "externa2developer1@exampledomain.com" ] }
* match response.contacts contains [ 'externaldeveloper1@exampledomain.com', 'externa2developer1@exampledomain.com' ]
* match response.contacts[1] == 'externa2developer1@exampledomain.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your karate code

```
When method POST
Then status 200
* match  response.contacts contains ['externaldeveloper1@exampledomain.com', externa2developer1@exampledomain.com]
```

Is the same as you are using in your test, then the syntax error is that you forget to put the second mail in quotes.

Correct:

```
When method POST
Then status 200
* match  response.contacts contains ['externaldeveloper1@exampledomain.com', 'externa2developer1@exampledomain.com']
```

The reason why

```
* assert response.contacts.[0] == 'externaldeveloper1@exampledomain.com'
```

fails is simple. The dot after `contacts` is to much.

Correct:

```
* assert response.contacts[0] == 'externaldeveloper1@exampledomain.com'
```